# PHP how to use if $var['table'] else if ['table'] is null to display blank

Tags: php

I have a database that returns results based on query:

```
<?php foreach ($data as $key=> $item) { ?>
<tr>
<td class="text-left"><?php echo ucwords(strtolower($item['biz_name'])); ?></td>
<td class="text-left"><?php echo '<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q='. $item['loc_LAT_centroid'] .','. $item['loc_LONG_centroid'] .'">'.ucwords(strtolower($item['e_address'])).'</a>'; ?></td>
<td class="text-left"><?php echo ucwords(strtolower($item['e_city'])); ?></td>
<td class="text-center"><?php echo strtoupper($item['e_state']); ?></td>
<td class="text-center"><?php echo $item['e_postal']; ?></td>
<td class="text-center"><?php echo $item['biz_phone']; ?></td>
<?php if (empty($item['web_url'])) {
    <td class="text-center"><?php echo ''; ?></td>
}
else {
    <td class="text-center"><?php echo '<a href="'. $item['web_url'] .'" >'."View Site".'</a>'; ?></td>
} ?>
```

I'm obviously doing this wrong but this is what I've pieced together so far.  What I'm trying to do is have the web_url table field display blank if the value is null, otherwise display "View Site" if it contains a value.  I'm fairly new to php so any help is appreciated.

I get a parse error on this line presently:

```
<?php if (empty($item['web_url'])) {
```

Comment: I think you are mixing up javascript syntax with PHP. You probably want `if (empty($item['web_url']))`

Comment: Why are you checking `$item.web_url` in your if statement? Shouldn't it be `$item['web_url']`? Also - your if statement will print 'Unlisted' if `web_url` is _not_ empty, which is probably the reverse of what you want

Comment: Sorry I posted a draft version the code, but I'd just want the Unlisted to equal an empty string.  I knew I wasn't calling the 'web_url' correctly in my syntax, thus the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) in that case:

```
<td class="text-center">
    <?php echo (isset($item['web_url']) && !empty($item['web_url'])) ? ('<a href="'. $item['web_url'] .'" >'."View Site".'</a>') : ''; ?>
</td>
```

Comment: I tried that after your suggestion however all results still display the "View Website" string regardless if the var is null.  If the query returns null for 'web_url' nothing displayed (since the website can't be viewed)

Comment: What is the possible scenarios for `web_url`? It could be a empty string? Can you insert a new td with a `var_dump($item['web_url'])` to be sure of what are the values? Anyway, I updated the answer, now checking if exists and it's not empty

Comment: yes, if the url isn't in the database, it'll return an empty string.  if that's the case, I'd like the field to be left blank, otherwise "View Site"  trying your suggestion now

Comment: Clyff thanks so much for your help, worked beautifully!  There's a missing ] after the 2nd web_url but you're a lifesaver.  Thanks again.

Comment: it wont let me upvote this answer due to my lack of reputation but others who can, please do

Comment: Cool, I'm glad I could help. Don't forget to take a look in that link, there is more examples of not just ternary, but another operators as well.